# Openvpn client-to-client connection reencrypted at Server?

Tags: openvpn

currently i'm using a site-2-site openvpn setup. The routers en/decrypt all traffic that goes from one net to another. One of them is the Openvpn server. This works but performance is not as good as possible. I think the limiting factor is the cpu power of the router.

Would it be better if i use client-to-client connections and access the fileserver in the one net from a pc in the other, because the openvpn-server does not have to decrypt the (whole) packets?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide additional information about the hardware of your openvpn server.
Openvpn server's should (generally) not chew up the resources of even a somewhat old computer.
Chances are the internet connection is the bottleneck and not the computer itself, but while we are at it, what internet connection do you use?

As for encryption/decryption, you'll get that even when you connect an openvpn client to another openvpn client.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not only be encryption but also compression. In its well-meant try to save bandwith (which you perhaps have plenty of today) a small cpu might indeed crumble under the additional load. Without knowing your hardware I'd say yes, it might be worth a shot to let the PCs do the work of encrypting/compressing the packets. I wouldn't be surprised if each of your PCs is more powerful than your router, so it's a promising approach.

Maybe try deactivating the compression in the routers first and see if that removes enough bottleneck before you start to rebuild your whole vpn setup.